# Getting Error whenever I try to save any file in my react CRA project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am using CRA and when I edit any of my project files and save I get this error as shown in the image.

I have already tried deleting node_modules , reinstalling and everything but still no luck.

I have to restart my local server every time after saving.

[image: Error Message Image Below]

Comment: Looks like the problem is with your code. See error message and try to comment out the related code mentioned in there.

Comment: Its not related to code, everytime I am trying to same some file, it shows this error @CodeThing